# F# SQLClient typeProvider reducing duplicate code

Tags: t-sql, f#, type-providers

I am trying to create a type safe data access layer in F# using FSharp.Data.SqlClient type providers to be callable from C#. I have highly complicated SQL queries that are performance critical but there are also several variations. 
Given the following (obviously simplified schema):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[company] (
    [id]                                INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [name]                              VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL)
```

I have the following F# code:

```
module CompanyDAL =
    open FSharp.Data // requires FSharp.Data.SqlClient package
    [<Literal>]
    let conn = "Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV13;Initial Catalog=TESTDB;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;Connect Timeout=30"
    [<Literal>]
    let baseQuery       = "select id, name from company where 1 = 1 "
    [<Literal>]
    let filterById      = "and id = @id"
    [<Literal>]
    let filterByName    = "and name = @name"
    [<Literal>]
    let queryFilteredById = baseQuery + filterById
    type GetCompanyById = SqlCommandProvider<queryFilteredById, conn>
    [<Literal>]
    let queryFilterbyName = baseQuery + filterByName
    type GetCompanyByName = SqlCommandProvider<queryFilterbyName, conn>
    type GetAllCompanies = SqlCommandProvider<baseQuery, conn>
    type Company = {
        Name    : string
        id      : int
    }

    let getCompanyById (runtimeConn:string) = 
        async {
            use query = new GetCompanyById(runtimeConn)
            let! result = query.AsyncExecute(id = 10) 
            return result
            |> Seq.map (fun x -> 
              { Name = x.name
                id = x.id })
            |> Seq.toArray
        } |> Async.StartAsTask

    let getCompanyByName (runtimeConn:string) = 
        async {
            use query = new GetCompanyByName(runtimeConn)
            let! result = query.AsyncExecute(name = "abc" )
            return result
            |> Seq.map (fun x -> 
              { Name = x.name
                id = x.id })
            |> Seq.toArray
        } |> Async.StartAsTask

    let getAllCompanies (runtimeConn:string) = 
        async {
            use query = new GetAllCompanies(runtimeConn)
            let! result = query.AsyncExecute() 
            return result
            |> Seq.map (fun x -> 
              { Name = x.name
                id = x.id }) 
            |> Seq.toArray
        } |> Async.StartAsTask
```

Is there any way I can reduce the number of duplication while maintaining the raw performance of type safe raw queries?

Comment: I haven't really used SqlCommandProvider so can't comment on its specifics but you could try and factor out the common parts into a function, and try making make it more generic.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried using

```
 type GetCompany = SqlEnumProvider<baseQuery, conn, provider>
```

Then I can write this code

```
GetCompany.Items |> Seq.where(fun (id, name) -> name = "xxx") |> printfn "%A"
```

So I can avoid duplication and pass a generic predicate `fun (id, name) ->` to the only `GetCompany` type.

Similarly,

```
GetCompany.Items |> Seq.where(fun (id, name) -> id = "1")
```

would work as well.

### Note

Anyway, notice that the above will filter in memory. In fact [Dynamic SQL is not permitted](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/issues/193) with this library, because it relies only on static analysis at compile time. If you need to construct queries dynamically, you can revert to raw ADO.NET or other light ORM.